# How can i put same calculation in the first row to second row of the table using JavaScript? did i miss something?

Tags: javascript

I've been using JavaScript to create new row on the table so that each input data will save in database. please refer example below.

Script for adding row on the table

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      var html='<tr><td><input type="text" size="2" class="form-control" name="qt[]" id="qt"
          oninput="calculate();" required></td>
          <input type="text" size="5" class="form-control" name="uc[]" id="cf" oninput="calculate();"
          placeholder="₱0.00" required></td>
          <td><center><input type="text" size="5"  class="form-control" name="ta[]" id="result"
          required></center></td><input type="button"  class="form-control" name="remove" id="remove"
          value="-"></td></tr>';

      var x = 1;
      $("#addd").click(function(){

          $("#tb_field").append(html);
      });
      $("#tb_field").on('click','#remove',function(){
          $(this).closest('tr').remove();
          x--;
      });

  });
</script>
```

Script for multiplying two input types in the first row of the table

```html
<script>
  function calculate() {
    var myBox1 = document.getElementById("qt").value;

    var myBox2 = document.getElementById("cf").value;

    var result = document.getElementById("result");

    var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;

    var format2 = myResult.toLocaleString("USD");

    document.getElementById("result").value = format2;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You're using element id's, and these have to be unique. The second row receives the same id's as the first row, so you cannot address these id's, they're not unique.

Comment: is it possible to use different way like each <td> will peform same calculation?

Comment: You could number the id's so they are unique again. `qt1`, `qt2`, etc. Then when you call `calculate()` you could give it the row number: `calculate(2)`.

Comment: Ah, that went better than I expected. Bravo.

Comment: but another problem occurred when i add another row in the 3rd row it wont calculate same problem i guess with the id's

Comment: Well, all the numbers have to match. So, in row 3 you should have `qt3` so you can use `calculate(3)`. You need to create your HTML in a function, like `newRowHtml(rowNumber)`, and use the `rowNumber` to give all the id's in the row their number so they are unique.

Comment: can you give me an example for this method? i don't know how?

Comment: OK, give me a moment....

Comment: Oh, I see you are using JQuery, that makes things somewhat simpler.... (hold on)

Comment: I'm missing bits of code to test this, how is the html table defined, and where does `#tb_field` fit in? Why `#addd` with three d's and what does `x` do?

Comment: You're also missing quite a few `<td>` in your html.

Comment: that x is a var that triggered when i click (-) button it will remove those row i don't want to display
also that #addd id is the button created in table to perform additional row

Comment: to make it short from the script are the same in the html code the difference is the id of the button like  in the script #remove and in the html #addd

Comment: It takes a bit of time to set this all up, and to debug it...

Comment: thanks for sharing knowledge you save me! thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I made [a working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a5z67btv/2/) example. The code is:

```
<table id="myTable">
</table>
<input type="button" name="addRow" id="addRow" value="+">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js?Version=43"></script>
<script>

function newRowHtml(rowNumber)
{
  return '<tr id="row'+rowNumber+'"><td><input type="text" size="2" name="qt[]" class="qt" oninput="calculate('+rowNumber+');" value="0" required></td><td><input type="text" size="5" name="uc[]" class="cf" oninput="calculate('+rowNumber+');" value="0" required></td><td><center><input type="text" size="5"  name="ta[]" class="ta" required></center></td><td><input type="button" name="remove" id="removeRow" value="-"></td></tr>';
}

var rowNumber = 1;
$("#addRow").click(function() {
  $("#myTable").append(newRowHtml(rowNumber));
  calculate(rowNumber);
  rowNumber++;
});
$("#myTable").on('click', '#removeRow', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});

function calculate(rowNumber)
{
  let row = $("#row"+rowNumber);
  let qt = parseInt(row.find(".qt").val());
  let cf = parseInt(row.find(".cf").val());
  row.find(".ta").val(qt * cf);
}

</script>
```

I have numbered the rows, which is easier than number cells, and make fully use of JQuery. I hope this makes some sense, and that you can adapt it to your needs.

You can, of course, use `parseFloat()` instead of `parseInt()`, but having values like `₱0.00` in your input could complicate things.

Comment: thanks for sharing knowledge you save me! thank you so much

Comment: can i ask 1 more favor? how to format those total amount into toLocaleString.("USD")
i`ve been trying this method just like in first row of the table but nothing happen :)

Comment: @RobertJhunVillapazLagang: If you have a Javascript variable, called `myVar`, you can do: `myVar.toLocaleString('en-US',{style: 'currency', currency: 'USD'})` and it will return US dollars.

Comment: good day sir i've been searching for solution for weeks but nothing came out i've been trying to put id's on the total amount but when i press + button it wont add another row how can i put currency on total amount in every row i added on the field? i try many things based what i see is you are using class in multiplying qnty and total cost but when i put id's on the total amount nothing happen did i missed something? please help me.

Comment: @RobertJhunVillapazLagang: You don't need to put id's on the total amount input to access it with JQuery. The row, in which this total amount input is embedded, has an id, and you can use this id to access the total amount input. Like this: `$("#row1 .ta").val();` for row number 1, and  `$("#row2 .ta").val();` for row 2, and so on.

Comment: can you make an example how do it? i don't know how? please